# SpriteNode is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create my User SpriteNode with the following Methode. The texture is Kladde and the Image is not empty too.

```
func spawnPlayer() {
    if didFirstTap == true && isGameOver == false {
        let collisionMask = CollisionCategory.Surrounding.rawValue | CollisionCategory.Platform.rawValue
        let x = self.frame.size.width / 4
        let y = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)
        let node = SKNode()
        node.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width + playerTexture!.size().width, 0)
        playerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture)
        playerNode!.setScale(1.0)
        playerNode!.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
        playerNode!.speed = 1.0
        playerNode!.zRotation = 0.0
        playerNode!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: playerNode!.size.height / 2)
        playerNode!.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        playerNode!.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        playerNode!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategory.Player.rawValue
        playerNode!.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionMask
        playerNode!.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionMask
        playerNode!.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake( 0, 0 )
        node.addChild(playerNode!)
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

I Hope someone knows, why my Node is invisible?

Comment: What is the position of node and what is the position of playerNode? Is there are reason your adding your player to a node and not directly into your scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at where the node is spawning:

`node.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width + playerTexture!.size().width, 0)`

Then on top of that you move the player in the position of the node

```
let x = self.frame.size.width / 4
let y = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)
playerNode!.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

This poor guy is way outside of the screen space.